# Unable to apply log function to a pyspark dataframe

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

so I have a large dataset (about 1 TB+) where I have to do many operations for which I have thought of using **pyspark** for faster processing. Here are my imports:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

try:
    import pyspark
    from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, SQLContext
except ImportError as e:
    raise ImportError('PySpark is not Configured')
    
print(f"PySpark Version : {pyspark.__version__}")
    
# Creating a Spark-Context
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(SparkConf().setMaster('local[*]'))
# Spark Builder
spark = SparkSession.builder \
            .appName('MBLSRProcessor') \
            .config('spark.executor.memory', '10GB') \
            .getOrCreate()
# SQL Context - for SQL Query Executions
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

>> PySpark Version : 2.4.7
```

Now, I want to apply `log10` function on two columns - For demonstrations, please consider this data:

```py
data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "B" : [4, 3, 6, 1, 8]
}))

data.head(5)
>> [Row(A=1, B=4), Row(A=2, B=3), Row(A=3, B=6), Row(A=4, B=1), Row(A=5, B=8)]
```

This is what I require: `log10(A + B)` i.e. `log10(6 + 4) = 1` for which I have made a function like this:

```py
def add(a, b):
    # this is for demonstration
    return np.sum([a, b])

data = data.withColumn("ADD", add(data.A, data.B))
data.head(5)

>> [Row(A=1, B=4, ADD=5), Row(A=2, B=3, ADD=5), Row(A=3, B=6, ADD=9), Row(A=4, B=1, ADD=5), Row(A=5, B=8, ADD=13)]
```

But, I can't do the same for `np.log10`:

```py
def np_log(a, b):
    # actual function
    return np.log10(np.sum([a, b]))

data = data.withColumn("LOG", np_log(data.A, data.B))
data.head(5)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a5726b6c7dc2> in <module>
----> 1 data = data.withColumn("LOG", np_log(data.A, data.B))
      2 data.head(5)

<ipython-input-12-0e020707faae> in np_log(a, b)
      1 def np_log(a, b):
----> 2     return np.log10(np.sum([a, b]))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Column which has no callable log10 method
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use native Spark functions:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd

data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "B" : [4, 3, 6, 1, 8]
}))

data = data.withColumn("LOG", F.log10(F.col('A') + F.col('B')))
```

But if you want, you can also use a UDF:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "B" : [4, 3, 6, 1, 8]
}))

def udf_np_log(a, b):
    # actual function
    return float(np.log10(np.sum([a, b])))

np_log = F.udf(udf_np_log, FloatType())

data = data.withColumn("LOG", np_log(data.A, data.B))

+---+---+---------+
|  A|  B|      LOG|
+---+---+---------+
|  1|  4|  0.69897|
|  2|  3|  0.69897|
|  3|  6|0.9542425|
|  4|  1|  0.69897|
|  5|  8|1.1139433|
+---+---+---------+
```

Interestingly it works for `np.sum` without UDF because I guess `np.sum` is just calling the `+` operator, which is valid for spark dataframe columns.